# Authenticating access to my GCM server

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-cloud-messaging

In my android application, I have utilized G+ logins to authenticate the user on the device, and I have implemented a basic GCM server to get a GCM registration ID for that device as well.

Once a device has both authenticated the user and received a GCM registration ID, I'd like it to let my server know that, for example, registration ID XYZ is associated with tim@gmail.com. This part I understand how to do. What I'm not sure of is how I can make sure that it's REALLY tim@gmail.com.

How can I be sure that the email/GCM registration ID pairs coming from devices is authentic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google allows you to [verify back-end calls from your Android app](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html) by utilizing [GoogleAuthUtil](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html)

> to retrieve a string called an “ID Token”. You send the token to your back end and your back end can use it to quickly and cheaply verify which app sent it and who was using the app.

By passing the ID token with your registration ID call to the server, you can verify that the message is authentic and from your Android app.